# How to restrict multi-tenant login to specific tenants via code?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, .net-5

I have built a very simple Razor Pages app that is hosted using the Azure free plan and which uses multi-tenant authentication.
It's a simple application, not an Enterprise Application.
It seems like tenant restrictions are what I'd need, but those seem to require a premium plan.

Is there some way to specify in code that only certain tenants are allowed? Basically, if a user signed in using a different domain account than what I've allowed, I want to send a 403 error (doesn't have to look pretty, as usually, only users from one or two specific tenants would sign in anyway, it's not a public website).

Like this, for all pages (pseudocode):

```csharp
if(!User.Identity.Name.EndsWith("@alloweddomain.com"))
{
    throw new NotAuthorizedException(); // Or HTTP 403
}
```

It would be even better if I could configure that somehow in the authentication configuration.
This is what I have so far (autogenerated by Visual Studio):

```csharp
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
                ;

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
                options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
            });
            services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMvcOptions(options => { })
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create an environment with multi-tenant login and restrict user .

Here are the steps i followed :

Created a Azure active directory tenant

[image]

In visual studio select Authentication account and provide my domain as below;

[image]

Here i have my client id which was created (App registration)

[image]

or we can create manually by going to Azure portal and we can select following to which account we want provide authentication

[image]

After mentioning client id and callbackurl as above now it allow users to login

[image]

Now, to restrict user to not allow to the webapp ,in your `startup.cs` change the default setting as below instead of `validateissuer = false` make it as `true` and .
provide the client id which mention in `app settings.json`
Here also we can provide multiple usser whom we want to allow by providing the client id

```
 ValidateIssuer = true,
valiadIssuer = new List<string>()
{"https://sts.windows.net/clientid***/" }
```

[image]

Please refer this Microsoft documentation for more information : [Build a multi-tenant daemon with the Microsoft identity platform endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-aspnet-daemon-webapp/build-multi-tenant-daemon-aad/) & to  [Restrict who can sign in to your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp#restrict-who-can-sign-in-to-your-application) .

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed example. I wouldn't be managing the tenants though (for example, this could be a university account). Would I still be able to get the client ID somehow?

Comment: You can get the client id from App registration(manually).

Comment: How? I don't have access to the tenant, I can only register apps in my own tenant.

Comment: You should have the admin permission to view the client id for the tenant, go to Azure Active directory>App registration>from overview section you can check the client-id and more details.
And refer this MS DOC for  [Use tenant restrictions to manage access to SaaS cloud applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/tenant-restrictions) .

Comment: But it’s not my tenant? I want to allow people to sign in with their university account, for example? I don’t have admin permissions for university tenants?

Comment: Could you please refer this MS DOC for : [What are the default user permissions in Azure Active Directory?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions)

Comment: Yes, users can sign in using their university accounts. I have set that up correctly. But how would I get the client ID? I cannot administer the university Azure AD, the university doesn't even know my app exists. And yes, tenant restrictions are EXACTLY what I need, but they require a premium plan, which I don't have.